# On intersections of exceptional divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, blow-ups

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective variety of dimension $n \ge 2$, $L$ a very ample line bundle on $X$ and $\pi: \widetilde{X} \to X$ be the blow-up along a closed subvariety of codimension at least $2$. Denote by $E$ the associated exceptional divisor. Is it true that for all $1 \le i \le n-1$, we have $(\pi^*L)^{n-i} E^i=0$?

Comment: By projection formula this vanishing holds if $\pi_*(E^i) = 0$ in Chow groups; this must be the case when $i$ is less than codimension of the center of the blowup. On the other hand, when $n = 3$, $i = 2$ and we blow up a curve, the answer is not necessary zero (it is roughly degree of the curve).

Comment: See [What's the cohomology ring structure of a blow-up?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394161/whats-the-cohomology-ring-structure-of-a-blow-up).

Comment: @EvgenyShinder and abx: Thanks for your comments.